# separate and re-sort with awk multiple fields

Tags: bash, awk, command-line

I have a file

**input.txt**

```
04120;2017-12-27;object1;2017-12-27;object2;2017-12-27;object3;2017-12-27;object4;2017-12-28;XXXXXX1;2017-12-28;XXXXXX2;2018-03-06;object5;2018-03-06;object6
06499;2018-05-30;object1;2018-05-30;object2;2018-05-30;object3;2018-05-30;XXXXXX1;2018-05-31;object4
04123;2017-12-28;object1;2017-12-28;XXXXXX1;2018-04-05;object2
04520;2018-02-11;object1;2018-02-11;object2;2018-02-16;XXXXXX1;2018-03-10;object3
04510;2018-02-09;object1;2018-02-09;object2;2018-02-09;XXXXXX1;2018-02-16;XXXXXX2;2018-04-04;object3
```

My log has different field numbers, separated by ";" . as in the example, where I have 7,9,11 or 17 fields
I need to save at the end of the line what the first entry XXXXXX and its date, and what object before it. removing these fields from the middle of the line

Ex:

```
from 
04123;2017-12-28;<b>object1;2017-12-28;XXXXXX1</b>;2018-04-05;object2
to
04123;2017-12-28;object1;2018-04-05;object2;<b>2017-12-28;object1;XXXXXX1</b>
```

the output would look like this:

```
04120;2017-12-27;object1;2017-12-27;object2;2017-12-27;object3;2017-12-27;object4;2018-03-06;object5;2018-03-06;object6;2017-12-28;object4;XXXXXX1
06499;2018-05-30;object1;2018-05-30;object2;2018-05-30;object3;2018-05-31;object4;2018-05-30;object3;XXXXXX1
04123;2017-12-28;object1;2018-04-05;object2;2017-12-28;object1;XXXXXX1
04520;2018-02-11;object1;2018-02-11;object2;2018-03-10;object3;2018-02-16;object2;XXXXXX1
04510;2018-02-09;object1;2018-02-09;object2;2018-04-04;object3;2018-02-09;object2;XXXXXX1
```

how to do command line in bash? trying with awk but i have not got it yet

Comment: Please always try to put your efforts too in your post as we all are here to learn, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Solutions are always given on shown samples, so always try to put all your possible permutations and combinations in single shot itself else it will be re-work for people who have replied to your post.

Comment: thanks for the feedback @RavinderSingh13, I am learning, I will edit and put my reality to avoid this. I'm still learning and in this case I had no idea how to do it

Comment: We all are learning here honestly :) I would request you try to learn from these answers and try to apply by yourself, if you are not able to do may be then open a new thread etc, editing existing thread with many answers is not recommended, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: ok, I returned the original question and I will open a new topic, grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Improving my previous solution too now.

```
awk --re-interval '
match($0,/object[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+.*X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}|object[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/){
  value2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  num=split(value2,array,";");
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) array[1],array[num],substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1),array[2],array[1],array[3]
}
'  OFS=";"  Input_file
```

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk --re-interval '
match($0,/object[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+.*X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}|object[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2};X+[0-9]+;[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}/){
  value1=value2=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
  sub(/.*;/,"",value1);
  split(value2,array,";");
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) array[1],value1,substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1),array[2],array[1],array[3]
}
'  OFS=";"  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
04120;2017-12-27;object1;2017-12-27;object2;2017-12-27;object3;2017-12-27;object4;2018-03-06;object5;2018-03-06;object6;2017-12-28;object4;XXXXXX1
06499;2018-05-30;object1;2018-05-30;object2;2018-05-30;object3;2018-05-31;object4;2018-05-30;object3;XXXXXX1
04123;2017-12-28;object1;2018-04-05;object2;2017-12-28;object1;XXXXXX1
04520;2018-02-11;object1;2018-02-11;object2;2018-03-10;object3;2018-02-16;object2;XXXXXX1
04510;2018-02-09;object1;2018-02-09;object2;2018-04-04;object3;2018-02-09;object2;XXXXXX1
```

***NOTE:*** Only old version of `awk` is having `--re-interval` you could remove it in case your `awk` version is new.

Comment: worked a part ... in an example with more fields did not work

ex: in this case no<br>

    04120;2017-12-27;object1;2017-12-27;object2;2017-12-27;object3;2017-12-27;object4;2017-12-28;XXXXXX1;2017-12-28;XXXXXX2;2018-03-06;object5;2018-03-06;object6;2018-03-06;object7;2017-12-28;XXXXXX3;2018-03-06;object8

Comment: @IgorTorres, solution was prepared by seeing sample input in case it is not matching your actual input request you to please update your sample with complete details too.

Comment: sorry for not having done this before, I edited the post with a real case

Comment: @IgorTorres, ok I replied in another post now, please comment there only for updates, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `gensub()`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/(;[^;]+)(;[^;]+)(;XXX[^;]+)(.*)/,a) {
   $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1] gensub(/;[^;]+;XXX[^;]+/,"","g",a[4]) a[2] a[1] a[3]
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
04120;2017-12-27;object1;2017-12-27;object2;2017-12-27;object3;2017-12-27;object4;2018-03-06;object5;2018-03-06;object6;2017-12-28;object4;XXXXXX1
06499;2018-05-30;object1;2018-05-30;object2;2018-05-30;object3;2018-05-31;object4;2018-05-30;object3;XXXXXX1
04123;2017-12-28;object1;2018-04-05;object2;2017-12-28;object1;XXXXXX1
04520;2018-02-11;object1;2018-02-11;object2;2018-03-10;object3;2018-02-16;object2;XXXXXX1
04510;2018-02-09;object1;2018-02-09;object2;2018-04-04;object3;2018-02-09;object2;XXXXXX1
```

Comment: not work

awk: syntax error at source line 1 source file tst.awk
 context is
  >>> match($0,/(;[^;]+)(;[^;]+)(;XXX[^;]+)(.*)/, <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 5

Comment: Like the answer says, it requires GNU awk.